# `then` not a function error when invoking function returning Promise.all in await expression

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await

I have a function with a loop that creates an array of promises that I pass to Promise.all, which I'm then attempting to return to an `await` expression in the main function.

When I take the returned object and attempt to invoke `then` on it (which I would have thought was a promise), it doesn't appear to be a promise anymore. I'm receiving the error

> TypeError: respPromise.then is not a function

Here's a simplified version of what I'm doing

```
const run = async () => {
  const fs = require('fs').promises

  const createThreeFiles = () => {
    const promiseArray = []
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      promiseArray.push(fs.writeFile(`file${i}.txt`, `This is the text for ${i}`))
    }
    return Promise.all(promiseArray)
  }

  const respPromise = await createThreeFiles()

  respPromise
  .then(fileInfos => {
    console.dir(fileInfos)
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error)
  })
}

run()
```

If I change the `createThreeFiles` function and invoke `then` immediately off of `Promise.all(promiseArray)` there is no problem at all invoking then.

```
  const createThreeFiles = () => {
    const promiseArray = []
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      promiseArray.push(fs.writeFile(`file${i}.txt`, `This is the text for ${i}`))
    }
    return Promise.all(promiseArray)
                    .then(values => {...})...
    // the above works without error. 
  }
```

So I think I must have something not quite right with the use of `async/await`, but for the life of me I'm not sure what. I've read the docs and looked for things to fix (and also I'm new to `async/await`) but so far, no luck. I've checked docs on [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all), [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await), and [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) as well as read a couple of articles. I've checked things like the following:

- Make sure I'm invoking `await` in a function declared as `async`. Check.
- Declare the `createThreeFiles` function as `async`. No change.
- Do the immediate above *and* move `Promise.all` into an `await` expression. No change, and the linter complained that I'd already used `await` when I invoked `createThreeFiles`.

At this point, I'm just grasping at straws. I can move this logic back out of the function, but was trying to refactor and optimise my code, so tell me, how do I correctly return the promise of `Promise.all` when returned from a function invoked in an `await` expression?

Comment: "Make sure I'm invoking await in a function declared as async. Check" but it isn't! `createThreeFiles` is not declared as async.

Comment: here no need of then(). you can directly write console.log(resPromise)

Comment: @phuzi from the docs, "The `await` operator is used to wait for a `Promise`. It can only be used inside an `async` function." The `run` function, the function in which `await` is being used above, is declared as `async`. There is no requirement that the function being invoked in the `await` expression be async.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you await a promise inside an async function it reslves directly to the value and not to a promise.

So this

```
const respPromise = await createThreeFiles()

respPromise
.then(fileInfos => {
  console.dir(fileInfos)
})
```

Should actually be this

```
const fileInfos = await createThreeFiles();
console.log(fileInfos);
```

Comment: Nice. Thanks for that!